# Python3 MechanicalSoup -- Basic Form Submission with aspx

Tags: web-scraping, mechanicalsoup

I want to grab traffic incident data from the CHP website: https://cad.chp.ca.gov/Traffic.aspx

There is a simple form in the upper left hand corner where the user selects a county, then a table of traffic incidents for that county appears.

I'm using MechanicalSoup to submit the form, but the request I'm getting back doesn't include the table of traffic data. You can try it yourself at the link above and see the table I'm trying to grab.

Here is my code:

```
import mechanicalsoup

browser = mechanicalsoup.Browser()

front_page = browser.get('https://cad.chp.ca.gov/Traffic.aspx')

# Grab the login form
county_form = front_page.soup.select("#form1")[0]

# Set the county in the form
county_form.select('#ddlComCenter')[0]['value'] = 'LACC' # LACC is the code for Los Angeles

# Submit the form
page2 = browser.submit(county_form, front_page.url)

# View the response
print(page2.soup)
```

The `page2.soup` object contains most of the page, but not the table that you see if you submit the form "by hand".

Am I missing something?